# XHR Request Returning Page Not Found

Tags: python, json, xmlhttprequest

The following is a simplified version of some code I am using to pull in the result of an XHR request as a Python object:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/?d=2015W33&isAggregate=false'
url = ''.join(url)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print response.text
```

The webpage where the XHR is called from is:

http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/England-Premier-League

The XHR request is generated when you select a match date from the calendar at the top of the page, as seen in Google Chrome Developer Tools. If you right click the link generated within the Developer Tools to open in a new tab, a JSON object is opened in the new tab.

If I try doing this programatically using the above code, `response.text` is displayed as:

```
ï»¿<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />

<title>WhoScored.com</title>

</head>

<body style="padding: 20px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; background-color:#222222;">

    <div style="margin:0 auto; padding: 40px 20px; width:560px; background-color:#fff;">

        The page you requested does not exist in <a href="http://www.whoscored.com">WhoScored.com</a>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The format of the XHR requests for this site have recently changed, requiring me to do some recoding, but I am not sure why I can no longer grab the JSON object with the above code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like they only go back to the beginning of the month. The URL you provided is from pretty far back. If you change `d=2015W33` to `d=2015W50` it will work.

Comment: i dont understand why that is as the XHR requests in dev tools work for any game week in any season to return a JSON object...

Comment: Works fine for me without the headers: `requests.get('http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/?d=2015W33&isAggregate=false')`.

Comment: are you getting output with that though? when i run it like that it just returns a blank.

Comment: Try `response.content`

Comment: still just returns a blank for anything other than game week 50.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97916/discussion-between-ianauld-and-gdogg371).

Comment: @gdogg371 say please, did you solve the issue?